# Calling a php function with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi I am using ajax to do a post request. I think what I want to do is call a function within a php file but am a little confused if and how you do this, could anyone shed any light on this? This is what I have in my js file:

```
  function callAjaxAddition2() {
  arguments0 = jQuery('#code').val();
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: file.php",
     data: {code: arguments0},
     success: function(data) {
       request( $posted )     
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

'request' is a function within the php file.

**Update** I think I should be able to trigger what I need to using this: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/wc_api-the-woocommerce-api-callback/ if I put the url into the url field however that doesn't seem to work, how might I use a callback with ajax post?

Comment: a variable that is passed in on the server side

Comment: @sudharsan I would let the code be the way it is, specially for syntax errors (though it's obvious).

Comment: Your PHP code will not be executed at the client end, it executes on the server and then the HTML/JS code will be rendered, you will have to keep your request function in another php file then make a ajax call to that file,

Comment: Try to check this related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

First fix this line with the missing opening quote `file.php"`.

You cannot call a PHP function through AJAX but can *trigger* when it needs to be called, the following demonstrates the same:

In your PHP, your code would be:

```
if(isset($_POST['code'])){
   #'code' here is the identifier passed from AJAX
   request($_POST['code']);
}
```

Once your function has been called, does the necessary and returns the output to AJAX, you can use the `data` parameter you have set to see what output was sent back from PHP:

```
success: function(data) {
       alert(data); //contains the data returned from the 
                    //PHP file after the execution of the function    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling on a php file via ajax call is like running the script that you pass in the `url` parameter.
You don't get access to the inner functions, all you can do is pass data and get response.

If you want the `request()` function to be called in the script, you will have to call it in the php script.